# ExtJS4 - Cross-store model deletion: Removing a model from a store by creating a model and setting it's ID

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building a web application and I have a Grid Panel A who has Store A that uses a Model A. When the user clicks a certain entry E with an ID and clicks the delete button, what I want to happen is to get Store B then remove the entry with the same ID as the selected entry E.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is some sort of "cross-store" model deletion. The model from Store A gets selected, but the entry from Store B gets deleted.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
var userStore = Ext.getStore('borrowerListStore'); //this is Store B
var model = Ext.ModelManager.create({
}, 'myAppLicationName.model.borrowerList'); //this is Model B

model.set("ID", personID); //person id here is the ID of Entry E selected earlier

Ext.getBody().mask('Starting Client Delete...');

userStore.remove(model); //I remove the model from the store

//then I sync the store
userStore.sync({
    success: function(batch){
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
        console.log('delete user details success');
    },
    failure: function(batch){
        Ext.getBody().unmask();
        console.log('delete user details failure');
    }
});
```

However, I am stuck on the masking screen.

I also tried loading the store first as such before I remove then sync the store:

```
userStore.load({
    callback: function() {
        userStore.remove(model);
    }
});
```

However, I still got stuck on the loading screen.

Is there any way to do a cross-store model deletion based on a model property? I know that I can get Store B then iterate through the models and then remove the one whose ID matches the ID of what the user selected. My issue with that is if I have a lot of records in my store, it would take a lot of time to search through those.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm an idiot.

I did something like:

```
userStore.getProxy().extraParams = {
    selectedUserID: personID
};
```

and I had a if-else handling part in the php if `selectedUserID` was passed, I'd query the database using that in my Where clause so I'd end up with 1 entry.